# On a sufficient condition for being a prime ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, several-complex-variables

Consider the ideal $I$ in $\mathbb{C}[z_{1},\ldots,z_{m}]$ generated by $\{p_{1},\ldots,p_{t}\}$, where $t\leq m$ and $p_{1},\ldots,p_{t}$ intersects completely i.e. the map $(p_{1},\ldots,p_{t}):\mathbb{C}^{m}\mapsto\mathbb{C}^{t}$ is a submersion $\forall w\in Z(I)$. If furthermore, we assume that $Z(I)$ is connected, then is it true that $I$ is prime?

I am not sure how complete intersection influences the condition. For example, if we relax the condition $Z(I)$ being connected and consider the ideal $\langle z_{1}z_{2},z_{1}+z_{2}-1\rangle \subset \mathbb{C}[z_{1},z_{2}],$ then $z_{1},z_{2}\notin I$, which means $I$ is not prime. But I am unable to find counterexamples that fits both the conditions and still not a prime ideal.

Also, note that complete intersection forces $\{p_{1},\ldots,p_{t}\}$ to be a minimal generator of $I$.

Comment: I don't know about that submersive criterion, but if we are talking about [complete intersections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_intersection), then $I = \langle x\cdot y \rangle$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Yeah. But i am insisting on $Z(I)$ being a submanifold. That's why i introduced the submersion criterion.

Comment: So it is non-singular? Then being connected implies that it is irreducible, because intersections of irreducible components are singularities.

Comment: Yes. it is irreducible as a variety which has no singular point(as it is a submanifold).

Comment: Intersection of irreducible components are singularities of $\bigcup_{i=1}^{t}Z(p_{i})$ but not necessarily of $Z(I)$. Take $Z(z_{1},z_{2})$ for example in $\mathbb{C}[z_{1},z_{2}]$. Then it is $\{0\}$, which is a singular point of $Z(z_{1}.z_{2})=Z(z_{1})\bigcup Z(z_{2})$ but in itself, it is a submanifold in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$.